# Literal string replacement in Perl when replacer has special characters

Tags: regex, string, perl

I'm having trouble with replacer strings that contain special characters with using `s///`:

```
> cat replace.pl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $orig_string = 'abc${abc}def';
my $replacer = '${abc}';
my $replacement = 'TEXT';
print "\nBefore replacement: $orig_string";
$orig_string =~ s/$replacer/$replacement/g;
print "\nAfter replacement: $orig_string";

print "\n";

exit;
```

Erroneous output:

```
> /usr/bin/perl replace.pl

Before replacement: abc${abc}def
After replacement: abc${abc}def
```

This works if I manually escape the `$` in `$replacer` as `my $replacer = '\${abc}';`, but the replacer will have an unknown number and set of special characters in production.

Perl version:

```
> /usr/bin/perl -v

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3)
```

Comment: Consider a templating function like fill_in_string from [Text::Template](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Template)

Comment: `use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $str  = 'abc${abc}def';
my $what = '\$\{abc\}';
my $to   = 'TEXT';

say "Before: $str";

$str =~ s/$what/$to/;

say "After: $str";
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```
$orig_string =~ s/\Q$replacer\E/$replacement/g;
```

This will quote replacer string and will treat all special regex meta characters are literals.

[Read more about quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

You ma also use:

```
$replacer = quotemeta($replacer);
```

before substitution.